# Using if operator in template literal string

Tags: javascript

I am try to add various IF() operators to check if an image exsists and if one price is greater than another, but not sure the correct syntax when working with template literals.

Here is a a function that loops over each product and outputs the title, image and price, just not sure how to use ternary operators here.

```
    if(products.length > 0) {
      products.forEach(function(product, index) {

        const productRow = `
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 init">
          <div class="product-item mb-0 wow fadeIn" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="500ms">
            <div class="product-thumb">
              <div class="reveal img-fluid">
                <a href="${product.url}"><img class="img-fluid" src="${product.images[0]}" /></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-content py-2">
              <h3><a href="${product.url}">${product.title}</a></h3>
              <p class="home-price-inline mb-0">
                <span class="js-price" data-default-price="{{ current_variant.price | money }}">${Currency.formatMoney(product.price_min)}</span>
                <s class="ml-0">${Currency.formatMoney(product.compare_at_price)}</s>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`;

        productRecomendationBody.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', productRow);//afterbegin is the first element directly after the parent element
      });
    }
```

Comment: See [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Alternately, you can set up variables ahead of time with the results you need then use those in the template literal.

Comment: You say you're trying to add `if` then say *not sure how to use ternary operators* - which do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render an image only when it's available then you can do something like this.

Refer this section

```
<a href="${product.url}">${product.images[0] ? '<img class="img-fluid" src='${product.images[0]}' />' : ""}</a>
```

```js
if (products.length > 0) {
  products.forEach(function(product, index) {

    const productRow = `
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 init">
          <div class="product-item mb-0 wow fadeIn" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="500ms">
            <div class="product-thumb">
              <div class="reveal img-fluid">
                <a href="${product.url}">${product.images[0] ? '<img class="img-fluid" src='${product.images[0]}' />' : ""}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-content py-2">
              <h3><a href="${product.url}">${product.title}</a></h3>
              <p class="home-price-inline mb-0">
                <span class="js-price" data-default-price="{{ current_variant.price | money }}">${Currency.formatMoney(product.price_min)}</span>
                <s class="ml-0">${Currency.formatMoney(product.compare_at_price)}</s>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`;

    productRecomendationBody.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', productRow); //afterbegin is the first element directly after the parent element
  });
}
```

Comment: as posted, this code yields a syntax error. You need a nested template for it to work properly.

Answer (score -1):

> I am try to add various `if()` operators
>
> ...
>
> just not sure how to use ternary operators.

With an `if` you split the string.

```js
var i = 2;
var row = `${i} second`; 
if (i!==1) 
  row+='s';
row += " to go";
console.log(row)
```

with a ternary you can also split the string and keep it inline (here, spread over multiple lines for clarity, but could be one line)

```js
var i = 2;
const row = `${i} second` 
            + (i!==1?"s":"") 
            + ` to go`;
console.log(row)
```

or you can put the ternary in a replacement, using `${}`

```js
var i = 2;
const row = `${i} second${i!==1?"s":""} to go`;
console.log(row)
```

Comment: Thanks @mehulcse for your suggestion, have now got a working solution for all require checks.